# Do SVG font glyphs prefer absolute over relative coordinates?

Tags: svg, svg-font

I've been playing with SVG fonts (and specifically crafting my own) this weekend, and found (a bit to my surprise) that they all seem to prefer absolute-coordinate paths, like this one from [Keyamoon](http://keyamoon.com/icomoon/#toDownload):

```
[...]
<font id="IcoMoon" horiz-adv-x="512" >
<font-face units-per-em="512" ascent="480" descent="-32" />
<missing-glyph horiz-adv-x="512" />
<glyph unicode="&#xe000;" d="M 512.00,192.00L 416.00,288.00L 416.00,384.00L 352.00,384.00L 352.00,352.00L 256.00,448.00L0.00,192.00L 64.00,192.00L 64.00,0.00L 224.00,0.00L 224.00,128.00L 288.00,128.00L 288.00,0.00L 448.00,0.00L 448.00,192.00 z" data-tags="home, house" />
[...]
```

Is there some good reason to (say, known bugs with some renderers), or can I go about usual Scour space-saving practices and stick to the all-lower-case drawing commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing prevents you from using whatever path commands are defined in svg inside the 'd' attribute of a <glyph> element. That's valid and will work just fine.

I'd suspect that the absolute commands you see on Keyamoon is just the result of a conversion from another font format to svg.

Comment: Thanks! The same is likely true of all the SVG fonts from fonts.com, too.